Interpreting Factor Coefficients for an Emerging Markets Fund against the Market and its Benchmark
I ran CAPM, FF3, FF5 and Carhart models for an emerging markets fund against the FF data for emerging markets and against its own benchmark. I am constantly getting negative SMB's which shows relevant information about the fund but my SMB coeff go from being significant to being insignificant when regressing against the benchmark. What might be the reason behind this? The fund dictates its holding somewhat from said benchmark and is actively managed long-term oriented capital growth emerging markets fund.
Further, would I be correct in assuming that momentum is insignificant as it takes recent performance into account whereas the fund looks at long-term (5-7 yrs) in terms of performance.
As per my understanding, the reason for SMB being insignificant could be that against the market, the size effect is more pronounced as it has a broader size diversification whereas with the benchmark, which has similar large sized factor, it leads to having an insignificant SMB.
Finally, I would appreciate of anyone could give any substantial reasons for the HML, CMA and RMW factors not being significant as well please.
Thank you!
Any help on this would be appreciated

Does the benchmark have a SMB exposure?

@Arshdeep yes, the benchmark also has high SMB exposure. Added the regressions there for clearer reference

Then you have a confounder, and you should interpret this as "the portfolio has no SMB exposure over and above what can be explained/captured by the benchmark"

@Arshdeep but what would that mean for the statistically significant results I got for the market? Would those results be wrong as well?  As per my understanding, the reason for SMB being insignificant could be that against the market, the size effect is more pronounced as it has a broader size diversification whereas with the benchmark, which has similar large sized factor, it leads to having an insignificant SMB.

Kind of. BTW I am NOT suggesting that either result is wrong. This is a direct consequence of the SMB exposure of benchmark being higher than SMB exposure of the market portfolio, and is also encouraged by the fact that correlation b/w benchmark and portfolio is high. This doesn't mean portfolio has 0 SMB exposure, it means whatever SMB exposure it has is captured in the benchmark's SMB exposure.

To answer your first question, the portfolio has a higher SMB exposure than the market. The portfolio has a similar SMB exposure as the benchmark.

@Arshdeep thanks for that! It makes sense. Any potential suggestions for the rest of the factors? spec MOM?

MOM interpretation isn't correct. It's just saying, the portfolio isn't tilted towards either high momentum or low momentum stocks.
